# Minimum / Maximum absolute position in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What is the best approach to restricting an absolutely positioned element's position, ideally in pure CSS?

I know that the following isn't possible but I guess what I'm looking for would look something like:

```
.stickyElement{
   bottom-max:auto;      
   bottom-min:0px;
   top-max: auto;
   top-min: 100px;
 }
```

That would allow an element to move to a position no less than 100px from the top of it's containing, positioned element.

An example (and my initial) use case for this is a menu that scrolls as part of a page but stops scrolling when it hits the top of a viewport. (Sticky menus?) an example of which can be seen on this page:
http://spektrummedia.com/startups

I fully expect that this is not possible without using some Javascript but I thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: the url you give does this with javascript changing the position of the element from relative to fixed

Comment: Thanks @Circadian. I understand that. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of doing anything like this in CSS - or if there are any intended updates to future CSS versions that would allow for this.

Comment: I do not know that there is a way to ascertain the dimensions and positioning within the window using solely CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### position: sticky

There have been [discussions](http://www.google.com/#q=site:w3.org+position+sticky) in the W3C about this in recent years. One proposal is the addition of a `sticky` value for the `position` property.

```
.content {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position:    -moz-sticky;
    position:     -ms-sticky;
    position:      -o-sticky;
    position:         sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

This is currently supported in Chrome 23.0.1247.0 and later as an experimental feature. To enable it, enter `about:flags` for the URL address and press enter. Then search for "experimental WebKit features" and toggle it between enabled and disabled.

On the [html5rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit) website, there's a working [demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html).

Strictly speaking, this is an implementation of sticky content, and not a general-purpose way to limit the minimum or maximum position of an element relative to another element. However, sticky content might be the only practical application for the type of the behavior you're describing.

Comment: This is great. But we have to wait a few years to be able to use this :(

Answer (score 10):

I know this post is old, and I might be a little late to it, but to anyone still wondering how to do this i would suggest checking out the [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) method in CSS, you could do something like this:

`top: clamp(30px, 10vw, 50px);`

Which would set the min top value to 30px, the ideal value to 10vw, and the max value to 50px.

Comment: That was a really good suggestion and it worked for me. In my case, I had to use it like this: `top: clamp(0px, 10px, calc(100% - 10px));`
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

As there is no way to build this for all major browsers without the use of JavasScript I made my own solution with jQuery:

Assign `position:relative` to your **sticky-top-menu**. When it reaches the top of the browser window through scrolling the position is **changed** to `positon:fixed`.

Also give your **sticky-top-menu** `top:0` to make sure that it sticks to the top of your browser window.

Here you find a working [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/muffls/mhxQ8/3/).

---

**HTML**

```
<header>I'm the Header</header>
<div class="sticky-top-menu">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Some content...</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var headerTop = $("header").offset().top + $("header").outerHeight();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerTop) {
        //when the header reaches the top of the window change position to fixed
        $(".sticky-top-menu").css("position", "fixed");
    } else {
        //put position back to relative
        $(".sticky-top-menu").css("position", "relative");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sticky-top-menu {
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This solution has a problem: when the time comes to make it fixed, a "jump" in the content can be seen as the sticked DOM node is removed from its original position in the DOM tree, causing the remaining nodes to move up. A proper solution should leave the rest of the content untouched.

Answer (score 3):

A media query expression that defines the distance between body 0X 0Y and browser-window 0X 0Y would allow elements to be made sticky after page is scrolled

No such expression has otherwise been proposed and is not supported by any browser, to my knowledge, but it would be a useful expression to allow dynamic configuration of sticky elements, such as menu bars that are sticky after page is scrolled past head, without use of JavaScript.

```
.this element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}

@media (max-scroll: 200px 0) {
  .this.element {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to restrict an element that was positioned using absolute positioning using solely CSS.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If the question doesn't have an answer, we should not post "answers".