# Is there a css max-top property

Tags: css

We have

```
max-width    

min-width
```

I want

```
 max-top
```

Example

```
#myclass{
position: fixed;
max-top: -10 !important;
height: 130px;
}
```

If someone add to myclass by javascript/jquery. If top <-10 => It will affect, but when top < -10. It must be top = -10.

```
<div id="myclass" style="top: -130"> 
dgsagjl
</div>
```

How can I do it in CSS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum / Maximum absolute position in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164803/minimum-maximum-absolute-position-in-css)

Comment: *If someone* --> that someone is you? because if you can change that logic you can implement a max-top using max() and CSS variable

Comment: @bluejambo: I have been tested your link. But I want when top <=-10 it always done.

Comment: @Temani Afif I know, but sometime we used library, example https://fullcalendar.io/. It is too difficult when we edit javascript from them

Comment: Using pixel is kind of a max and min property.

Comment: @HongVanVit, I wasn't sure if this is what you were looking for but it looked promising. I guess it wasn't helpful, my bad, but that means I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: @bluejambo you are welcom. I really want to explain more. But my English is not good.